# $ in '--global-js-name==', JQuery compatibility and Sublime Text - Build Systems

Tags: jquery, dart, sublimetext3, build-system, dart2js

By default **JS** script generated by **dart2js** has global name **$** same as **JQuery** so it can be problematic to use both simultaneously.
To solve this problem **dart2js** has parameter **--global-js-name=={GLOBAL NAME}** but **{GLOBAL NAME}**  must match **\$[a-z]*** (example: *$dart*). In the **Sublime Text - Build Systems**,  **$** must be escaped with **'\\'**

Working parameter example:

```
"--global-js-name=\\$dart"
```

Resulting JS will start with something like:

```
// Generated by dart2js, the Dart to JavaScript compiler.
(function($dart){var A={}
delete A.x
var B={}
delete B.x
var C={}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I posted this "Answer Question" for those who might have same problem. It took me reasonably long time to figure out.*